# Запятая перед И в ССП

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Возникли споры с филологами по поводу постановки запятой под цифрой 1 в следующем предложении. Сразу скажу, что это задание из демоверсии ЕГЭ, то есть предполагается, что школьники смогут ответить верно.

```
В детстве Илюша был впечатлительным ребёнком (1) и он очень любил слушать сказки (2) которые рассказывала ему няня (3) потому что в них было много чудесного (4) и (5) добро всегда побеждало зло.
```

Здесь может показаться, что части «Илюша был впечатлительным ребёнком» и «он очень любил слушать сказки» имеют общий второстепенный член – «*в детстве*». В детстве Илюша был впечатлительным ребёнком, в детстве он любил слушать сказки. В таком случае запятая не нужна.

Однако в то же время есть правило, которое указывает, что запятая нужна: Перед союзом **и** запятая ставится также в тех случаях, когда он присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного предложения или повторяющим его: Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями *мельница*, и всё ещё *она* похожа на маленького человечка, размахивающего руками (Ч.). Именно на это правило ссылаются сотрудники ФИПИ, и в ключах к заданию запятая стоит.

Слышала также мнение, что запятую можно обосновать причинно-следственными связями.

Ситуация кажется неоднозначной. Кто прав?

Comment: А где описано такое правило? Где множество примеров такой запятой? Это предложение — ‟Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями ...” — не имеет смысла вообще, так как здесь неправильно употреблена частица ‟все еще”.

Comment: Правило описано у Розенталя. Примечание к правилу 1 из параграфа 30 в "Справочнике по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация". Именно на это ссылаются сотрудники ФИПИ. В этом правиле есть ещё один пример: "Ты всегда был строг ко мне, и ты был справедлив".

Comment: Скорее всего, Розенталь неправильно проинтерпретировал запятые в такой ситуации: первое предложение не имеет смысла, а запятая во втором объясняется присоединительным характером предложения: «и ты был справедлив». Грамотеям следовало бы детально расписывать такого рода размытые моменты в справочнике Розенталя.

Comment: Jim Korbett, «скорее всего», это вы не способны въехать ни в Розенталя, ни в Чехова, и это ваши грамматические фантазии не имеют смысла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вне зависимости от правил, местоимение "он" чётко способствует присоединению (запятой), оно нарушает связь с общим элементом. Что даёт это местоимение? Оно указывает на дополнительную информацию — значение "и **ещё** он". Читать там без паузы — ну вообще не по-русски.

А так запятая не нужна:
*Вечером у Илюши много работы и ему нужно сделать уроки.* || Играет роль разный падеж (*Илюши; ему*). Хотя и здесь можно поставить запятую по той же причине.

Примечание: у Розенталя это правило не связано с общим элементом, то есть не сказано, что даже при наличии общего элемента запятую необходимо поставить, просто в самом примере (Чехова) он есть, так что это задание не для школы от слова совсем, где руководствуются лишь правилами и не разбирают нюансы, которые в правилах отсутствуют. Где их ещё разбирают, если не на этом сайте?

Comment: Не все запятые обозначают паузу. Запятая между сложносочиненными определенно не обозначает паузу, а обозначает отношения между сегментами сложносочиненного. Такая запятая позволяет автору обозначить то, какая часть сложносочиненного к чему относится. Эта запятая вообще не имеет никакого отношения к интонации.

Comment: Следующие два предложения имеют разный смысл и разную пунктуацию, но произносятся абсолютно одинаково: ‟В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки[нет запятой] и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода”(в газете сообщается и о заморозках, и даются рекомендации) и ‟В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки,[есть запятая] и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода”(в газете сообщается только о заморозках, а рекомендации дает говорящий).

Comment: Сложносочиненные предложения с соединительными или разделительными союзами как-бы все произносятся без паузы перед союзом.

Comment: @oleedd  Хотите пародию на впечатлительного Илюшу? В детстве Илюша был  впечатлительным мальчиком, и он очень боялся слушать сказки.  Огненные драконы и волки-оборотни снились ему потом всю ночь, он плакал и вскрикивал во сне. Родители строго ругали няньку, если она рассказывала ему сказки.

Comment: По поводу общего второстепенного члена. Сотрудники ФИПИ комментируют это так: «Сама грамматическая структура этих предложений, в обеих частях которого один и тот же субъект действия (в предложении, следующем после союза "и", подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного предложения или повторяющим его), подсказывает, что второстепенного члена предложения здесь нет и не может быть, следовательно, запятая перед союзом "и" ставится».

Comment: @JimKorbett К сожалению, вы не правы. Порой да, но точно не между сложносочинёнными. *Сложносочиненные предложения с соединительными или разделительными союзами как-бы все произносятся без паузы перед союзом* — вот это уже вообще из разряда абсурда. Скажу так: прочитать можно как угодно, но нужно уметь читать правильно.

Comment: @ОлесяКондрушина Подсказывает оно тем, кто хорошо чувствует язык, но точно не школьникам, которые вряд ли проходили то, чего нет в правилах. Разве что какой-то крутой учитель мог поделиться своими продвинутыми знаниями, расширяя школьную программу.

Comment: @Sharon В вашей пародии впечатлительность логически связана с тем, что идёт дальше (это лучше, интереснее), а в оригинале мысль о ней обрывается.

Comment: @Sharon Что делать с этой бредовой мыслью Jim Korbett? *Следующие два предложения имеют разный смысл и разную пунктуацию, но произносятся абсолютно одинаково...* Доказывать интересно что-то сложное, неочевидное. Но доказывать, что белое бело, сложно и скучно. Как же человек поймёт, кто автор последнего предложения (про то, что следует принять меры), если читать одинаково? Наверное, в таких случаях надо просто проходить мимо.

Comment: @oleedd Из моей пародии  следует, что союз  И  не ведет нас однозначно от впечатлительности к «сказочной» любви, как это может показаться. Это всего лишь частный случай, который автор истории  выдает за непременное следствие.

Comment: @oleedd Соглашусь с вами. Официально в экзамене все задания только базового уровня. Эту историю базовой вряд ли назовёшь, но в то же время попробуй докажи составителям, что такой пример из школьного экзамена лучше убрать.

Comment: @oleedd  Если разбирать все "странные" мысли, то на все остальное времени не хватит. Я не всех слушаю и не всё слушаю.

Comment: @ОлесяКондрушина А вот докажите тем, что у Розенталя это правило не связано с общим элементом (там вообще речь о простых предложениях, нескольких грамматических основах), что оно не запрещает отсутствие запятой при общем элементе. Так что пусть сошлются на другое правило, где это будет чётко указано, а его нет. Или пусть укажут на параграф в школьном учебнике (по которому все учатся), где это объясняется.

Comment: @Sharon Вообще не вижу связи между впечатлительностью и "потому что в них было много чудесного и добро всегда побеждало зло".

Comment: @oleedd Сказки полезны для детей с хорошим воображением, а чувствительного и впечатлительного ребенка фантастические образы могут напугать. Поэтому надо писать реальные истории про мальчика Илюшу, а не схемы составлять и по ним детей обучать. Казалось бы, чего проще, берите примеры из литературы и анализируйте их.  И к изящной словесности ближе будете и поймете на деле, а не на правилах, почему не надо ставить запятую. А сейчас этого не понимают (и не чувствуют)  ни дети, ни педагоги.

Comment: @Sharon *Казалось бы, чего проще, берите примеры из литературы и анализируйте их* — мне всегда казалось это очень сложным, это ж сколько нужно всего перечитать, чтоб найти там подходящие примеры — сиди и читай днями напролёт или нанимай читателей (разве составители учебников станут таким заниматься?). Гораздо проще — придумать пример самому. Но в этом (в примерах из литературы) авторитет Розенталя, а его нельзя цитировать в книгах, авторские права. Государству давно бы стоило всё выкупить и опубликовать для общественности.

Comment: Я не вижу ничего странного, если "по наводке" Розенталя или других авторов обращаются  к классике. Мне интересно другое: в чем истинная причина отсутствия запятой?  Вот это важно понять, а не формальные признаки искать. У меня пока ТАКАЯ ВЕРСИЯ: нам важно соединить два действия в ОДНУ СИТУАЦИЮ. В детстве Илюша был впечатлительным ребёнком и  очень любил слушать сказки. Ситуация понятна, так зачем ее делить на две части, какой в этом смысл? В детстве Илюша был впечатлительным ребёнком,  и  он очень любил слушать сказки. Зачем переход от одной темы к другой, что он дает? Так, наверное,  и везде…

Comment: @Sharon Скорее всего, на примеры тоже действуют авторские права. Можно втихаря взять один, но два в одной теме уже намекнут на плагиат. Хотя Розенталь сам брал многие примеры из других справочников. *Ситуация понятна, так зачем ее делить на две части, какой в этом смысл?* — разговорный вариант, добавление информации — "и ещё он". Звучит нормально, так часто говорят.